# Adding and deleting nested Json data with Knockout js

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

I have a problem with adding and deleting Json data.

First I get a model from server then convert it into JSON data.
And need add or delete json data.

Here is my json data:

```
{
        "$id": "1",
        "Number": "000100029304",
        "Title": "Test Title",
        "Status": "Ready",
        "StatusDate": null,
        "Author": null,
        "UpdatedDate": "2012-12-12T12:12:12",
        "Comments": "test comment",

        "Type": {
            "$id": "2",
            "Title": "Type #1",
            "UpdatedDate": "2011-11-11T11:1:11",
            "Name": "AAA",
            "Documents": [
              {
                  "$ref": "1"
              }
            ],
            "ID": 100
        },
        "DocOwner": {
            "$id": "3",
            "Name": "CEO",
            "Title": "General Director",
            "Documents": [
              {
                  "$ref": "1"
              }
            ],
            "ID": 1
        },

        "Links": [
          {
              "$id": "4",
              "DocumentId": 1234,
              "Name": "Some file1.xls",
              "Path": "\\\\mycomp\\folder\\Some file1.xls",
              "Type": 0,
              "Document": {
                  "$ref": "1"
              },
              "ID": 200
          },
          {
              "$id": "5",
              "DocumentId": 1234,
              "Name": "Some file2.xls",
              "Path": "\\\\mycomp\\folder\\Some file2.xls",
              "Type": 0,
              "Document": {
                  "$ref": "1"
              },
              "ID": 201
          },
          {
              "$id": "6",
              "DocumentId": 1234,
              "Name": "Some file3.xls",
              "Path": "\\\\mycomp\\folder\\Some file3.xls",
              "Type": 0,
              "Document": {
                  "$ref": "1"
              },
              "ID": 202
          },
        ],
        "ID": 1234
    }
```

As you can see there are some links and I could not add or delete new links.

I configured knockout like this:

```
 var Link = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        if (data != null) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
        } else {
            self.ID = ko.observable();
            self.DocumentId = ko.observable();
            self.Name = ko.observable();
            self.Path = ko.observable();
            self.Type = ko.observable();
            self.Document = ko.observableArray();
        }

    }
    var DocViewModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.doc = dataModel;
        //if (data != null) {
        //    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { Links: linkMapping }, self);
        //} else {
        //    self.doc.Links = ko.observableArray();
        //}
        self.addLink = function () {

            self.doc.Links.push(new Link({
                ID: null,
                DocumentId: null,
                Name: "New link",
                Path: null,
                Type: null,
                Document: null
            }));

        }
        self.removeLink = function (Link) {
            self.doc.Links.remove(Link);
        }

        self.saveJson = function () {
            var myJson = ko.mapping.toJSON(self);
            $("#txt").val(myJson);
        }
    }
    var linkMapping = {
        create: function (options) {
            return new Link(options.data);
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = new DocViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    });
```

But it does not work. How can I configure the knockout to fix it?

Thank you in advance.
https://jsfiddle.net/pa3zcvae/

Comment: You Document in the else part as an observable array but in the json object, it is an object.

Comment: Tried this, but nothing happened

`self.doc= ko.observableArray([]);`

`self.doc(dataModel);`

Comment: where is remove in  self.doc.Links.remove(Link); defined?

Comment: you can see it in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pa3zcvae/

Comment: I as cause that is where I am getting an error.

Comment: if i uncomment "if-else" clause in knockout model.It works, but existing links removes. if not i got an error :"JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/pa3zcvae/1/

You almost had it. What you have makes sense, but it was not playing nice with the mapping plugin. When I used your addLink method, the new links were a different type of object then the existing mapped objects. The solution is actually simpler than you would expect, as knockout automagically takes care of all the work.

```
var Link = {
  ID: ko.observable(),
  DocumentId: ko.observable(),
  Name: ko.observable(),
  Path: ko.observable(),
  Type: ko.observable(),
  Document: ko.observableArray()
}

var DocViewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.doc = dataModel;
  self.doc.Links = ko.mapping.fromJS(self.doc.Links);

  self.addLink = function() {
    var link = {
      ID: null,
      DocumentId: null,
      Name: "New link",
      Path: null,
      Type: null,
      Document: null
    };
    self.doc.Links.push(link);
  }

  self.removeLink = function(Link) {
     self.doc.Links.remove(Link);
  }

  self.saveJson = function() {
     var myJson = ko.mapping.toJSON(self);
     $("#txt").val(myJson);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = new DocViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Comment: Fraser did what I was about to suggest. He created the view model and uses the mapping plugin to create the model.  The remove function is part of that plugin so when you created your own vm without using it, you no longer had access to the remove function.